# I can't output my variable as a label in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I would like to put a variable in a Tkinter label that prints out the value of the variable 'x'.

I tried to follow the example from the Tkinter documentation but it still seems to give me a trace error 'in second_click lblx2.place(window)'

```
x = max(numbers)
y = min(numbers)
z = sum(numbers)
a = float(z / len(numbers))


var_x = StringVar()
var_x.set(x)

lblx2 = Label(window, textvariable=var_x, font=('Arial Bold', 15), bg='blue', fg='red')

lblx2.place(window)
```

I expect it to just place the number on my window like regular text but it does not print anything.

The full error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "REDACTED", line 1705, in __call__ return self.func(*args)
  File "REDACTED", line 49, in <lambda> btn['command'] = (lambda: second_click())
  File "REDACTED", line 102, in second_click lblx2.place(window)
  File "REDACTED", line 2188, in place_configure 
  File "REDACTED", line 1320, in _options cnf = _cnfmerge(cnf)
  File "REDACTED", line 104, in _cnfmerge for c in _flatten(cnfs):
TypeError: object of type 'Tk' has no len()
```

When I remove (window) from place, it stops giving the errors but still does not put the number on the window

Comment: Can you paste the full error?

Comment: why do you use `window` in `place()` ? Probably this gives you error.

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve].

Comment: if you use `place()` without arguments then it may not know where to put label. Use at least `place(x=.., y=..)` or use other method to put it - `grid()`, `pack()`

Comment: Don't use `place()` like this. `place()` has some very specific uses but mostly you will be using `grid()` and `pack()` for managing your layout. Personally I like to use `grid()` for just about everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the error is that `window` is not a suitable parameter for a Label object. Instead, it is used to change the location of the element. You could either

- turn it into this: `lblx2.place(x=whatever,y=whatever)` (note: replace whatever with the location)

or

- Remove the whole line of code entirely as it's unnecessary

Comment: If I remove that line of code how would I output the label itself?

Comment: @RoastedT You would use `lblx2.pack()`

Answer (score 0):

Don't see a problem. Please provide a full example, not just pieces of code one cannot simply run. Here is mine, that DOESN'T reproduce the issue, and it really doesn't get much simpler than this:

```
from tkinter import *
from random import random

x = random()

root = Tk()
var_x = StringVar()
var_x.set(x)
Label(root, textvariable=var_x).pack()
root.mainloop()
```